# Not null key while doing insert using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and was writing some test program.
I am wondering if its a must to have a table , one column of which will be updated using some kind of sequence.

For ex. I created a table

```
create table course(course_name varchar2(20));
```

and when I am defining Course.hbm.xml in the following way

```
 <class name="Course" table="COURSE" >
<property name="course">
            <column name="course"/>
        </property>

   </class>
```

I am getting an error in the XML file saying a declaration of "id" or something similar is expected. I can give the whole error message if required.

Comment: Yes, every table *should* have a primary key, and every entity *must* have an ID. Usually, the ID is mapped to the primary key, or course. Read the documentation. Also, if you're new to Hibernate, learn how to define the mapping with annotations. Using XML is obsolete and non-standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an ID column so hibernate can identify that row in the table. I'm not fluent in that oldschool hibernate xml mapping but it should look roughly like that:

```
create table course(id integer primary key, course_name varchar2(20));

<class name="Course" table="COURSE" >
  <id name="id">
    <!-- uses sequence, auto increment or whatever your DBMS uses for id generation -->
    <generator class="native"/> 
  </id>
  <property name="course">
    <column name="course"/>
  </property>
</class>
```

As a side note: mapping your entities with annotations is a bit more common nowadays. Makes it easier, especially for starters.